Keep Div on screen within another div
I want to be able to keep elements on the right side of a div within the same location (similar to position: fixed), however I want to keep the div within its parent. required format
I want the "Stays in view" element to not leave its parents div but stay within the viewport.
I've tried position: fixed however its very hard to keep it from overlapping other elements with multiple viewports and will leave its parents div.
Thanks Parth M for the help. With your suggested edits:
latest output

Perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

The position: sticky property on the .sticky element makes it stick to the top of its parent .sidebar when you scroll within the .container.
The top: 0; specifies that the element should stick to the top of the container. You can adjust this value to change where the element sticks within the viewport.
The position: relative; on the .sidebar ensures that the sticky element is constrained within the bounds of the .sidebar as you scroll.


.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 200vh;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        scrollable child
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sticky">
            Stays in view
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




That's almost perfect thank you! Just realised due to footer, it leaves the parent div at the bottom of the page due to needing to stay within view (it leaves by like 50px) is there an easy fix?

Think I'll try making the floating div smaller

Can you please share an output screenshot so I can help?

I've attached the latest output

Use position: sticky;


.left_col{
  width:25%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange);
  height:2000px;
  margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
}

.right_col{
  width:calc(75% - 20px);
  background:grey;
  height:2000px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left_content{
  height:100%;
  width:48%;
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, orange);
}

.right_content{
  width:48%;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
  position: sticky;
  right:0;
  top:20px;
}
<div class="left_col"></div>

<div class="right_col">
    
  <div class="left_content"></div>
  <div class="right_content"></div>
  
</div>



